# Need function to write files incrementally

Tags: r

I have a function to generate simulation data and write it out to csv files.  This is working fine, but it does not write out the files until the function completes.  I would like it to write a file at the end of each for loop.  Any tips are much appreciated.

Truncated Code Block:

```
for (m in 1:M){

simulation code....

write.csv(userDF, file=filename, row.names=FALSE) 
}
```

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or at the least a little bit of code... add a write step at the end of each loop...

Comment: ... using `write.csv(..., append=TRUE)`. Look at `?write.csv` or `?write.table`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `flush` function. You would need to reference something of a connection type so perhaps

```
for (m in 1:M){
  simulation code....
  filx=file("filename")
  write.csv(userDF, file=filx, row.names=FALSE) 
  flush(filx)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, to append to the same growing file on each iteration.  It's definitely writing each loop!

```
library(readr)
startfile=TRUE  
for(index in 1:9){

  ... # make your dataframe here

  ## The first time through the loop, don't append. 
  ## Also, this will write the column names

  write_csv(as.data.frame(result),"result.csv", append=!startfile)

  ## On subsequent iterations, append your dataframe to the file
  startfile=FALSE
  }
```